# how to implement single-signon?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, sso

Want to create a intranet portal where all users after authenticated by windows domain controller should not login again in to SharePoint to access SharePoint intranet portal. What steps should be taken to implement this? Is Active Directory federated service required to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to use Active directory Federated Service.Windows Authentication is a way to go.

*The Windows authentication type takes advantage of your existing Windows authentication provider (AD DS) and the authentication protocols that a Windows domain environment uses to validate the credentials of connecting clients.*

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#planwin

Comment: If you use IE and put your intranet URL in the Local Intranet Zone the browser will not ask for credentials